# Override a custom numbering format in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

I'm using a custom mulilevel list in a large word document. I'm using top level headings as chapter headings. Accordingly, the number format is set to "Chapter 1:". This works really well and I like how it shows up in my table of contents.

My last two chapters however, are really appendices. Is there any way to override the numbering format just for these chapters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just a separate list with your different number formatting and apply it to the last two headings, otherwise if you want to have the same effect with just one list you could make one of the other list levels of the multi level list have the custom format but keep the indentation the same as the previous list (see image below). Then in your document simply <kbd>Tab</kbd> the last few paragraphs to change the list appearance.

[image]